# Do we get a access.log entry for content served from cache in nginx

Tags: nginx, cache

For a configuration that looks like

```
http {
    proxy_cache_path /etc/nginx/cache keys_zone=one:10m;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    server {
        proxy_cache one;
        listen 80;
        server_name x.y.in www.x.y.in;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header HOST $http_host;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1234;
            proxy_redirect off;
        }
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
    }
}
```

I was doing the ab (apache benchmark). And interestingly, I did not see anything in access.log file for cached content, I can see that some files popped up in the cache directory that I had specified.

Is that behavior expected, does cached content not show up in access.log ? Is it configurable ?

Went through the nginx docs as well, could not find anything related to this.

Comment: A don't see access_log directive

Comment: It is there, this is a part of the code. I will change the question and add original code snipped. It is from 2 files actually. 1 nginx.conf and other server block in sites-enabled